# Литература по Python

Tags: python, книги

Уважаемые, подскажите пожалуйста полезную литературу (на русском) либо же уроки. Просто в сети Интернет очень много различного, а красиво и понятно написанного мало. Интересует именно ВЕБ-дизайн. Спасибо.

Comment: Если веб-дизайн, изучайте html/css/графику, при чем тут Пайтон?

Answer (score 3):

Learn Python the hard way, Dive into Python

Comment: да это наше все=)